# Boto get_all_instances method fails with InvalidInstanceID.NotFound error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I am using boto to fetch all my instances from AWS EC2. The code is as follows :

`conn.get_all_instances(filters={'tag-value': 'some_server'})`

This was working fine until recently I upgraded 2 of my servers from m1.large instances to m3.large instances. I achieved the upgrade by stopping the instance, changing the instance type and restarting the instance.

However, since making that change, all my scripts which make the get_all_instances call fail with the below error and stacktrace :

`<Code>InvalidInstanceID.NotFound</Code><Message>The instance IDs 'i-5bb7a48b, i-f9ca392d' do not exist</Message>`

More surprisingly, this error is sporadic. Sometimes the method fails, sometimes it passes. Any pointer, as to why this happens?

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>I found a similar issue here if it helps : https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/7906</sub>

Comment: Is the error consistent on all invocations of the code? Does any of the filters contain hardcoded instance ids e.g. i-5bb7a48b? If it is inconsistent and happens some times, then the reason might be eventual consistency. Have seen this error in cases where a new node was just added but a call to get_all_instances failed due to this node (call can be in separate process as well). Catch exception and retry is the recommended solution in this case.

Comment: Yes the error is consistent. No, the filters do not contain hard-coded instance ids. Catch exception and retry seems to be the crude way to solve it, any more elegant solution?

Comment: Check the EC2 API status for the region you're running against when you have this issue.  I've had sporadic issues in us-east-1 in the past few days, and the error returned made it sound like it was on my end (it wasn't), not theirs.

Comment: Does the error message always contain the same instance ids? Can you check the state of these instance ids in your account. Consistent behavior is definitely unexpected.

Comment: Yes the error message always contains these ids. These instance ids no longer exist in my account!

Comment: @Yahya - in that case you might want to look at AWS API request made by boto under the cover. One of the ways to figure out the exact API call (DescribeInstances) in this case will be by enabling debug option. Refer to debug control in boto configuration (set it to 2), http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html#boto